# How to clear TextView in android when start new Activity?

Tags: android, textview

If I have some `TextView` which create programmatically as follows:

```
textChallenge = new TextView(context);
    textChallenge.setTypeface(fontJoan);
    textChallenge.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textChallenge.setText("99");
    textChallenge.measure((int)Define.getScreenWidth(), (int)Define.getScreenHeight());
    textChallenge.layout(0, 0, 200, 200);
    textChallenge.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20);
    textChallenge.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    textChallenge.buildDrawingCache();
```

The question is, Do I have to clear this `TextView` when I start new `Activity`?

Because I found that if I create this `TextView` in great amount, it may cause some

problems to my memory.

This is how I use `TextView`:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
canvas.drawBitmap(textUser.getDrawingCache(), posX, posY, null);
invalidate()
}
```

I found that when I create a lot of `TextView` and check allocation by using

`(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1048576L)`, it increases a little bit.

How can I suppose to remove `TextView` allocation completely?

Comment: You are saying that you have different class which provides `TextView` to your whole application or different `Activity`. If that'z the case then you need to clear it out every time you used that `TextView`.

Comment: No, I just create this `TextView` in every `Activity`. I use `Canvas` and draw this `TextView`. Do I have to recycle `TextView` if I draw it?

Comment: this.textview.setText("")

Comment: recycle the textView only if you donot need one in the future and let the garbage collector collect it. You donot need to clear it if your not destroying the activity (mainly it depends on your goals, what do you want to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

use this to clear textview

this.textview.setText("")

Comment: I can't use `findViewById` because I have to create by programmatically.

Comment: `NullPointerException` when I try to set new text

Comment: can u give full code, so i can check what problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
textChallenge = null;
```

if you wish to destroy its object. But its not necessary unless there are too much dynamic objects, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Just write below code :-

```
textChallenge.setText("");
```

Comment: I got Exception `NullPointerException` when I try to set new text

Comment: add my code after this textChallenge = new TextView(context);